# Creating a pie-chart in excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pie-chart

I am new to VBA and am trying to learn how to create a pie-chart out of certain values on the Excel spreadsheet. I know how to do the bar charts, but I was wondering whether you guys are aware of online resources or tutorials for this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Tools` -> `Macro` -> `Record New Macro` produces this code which you can then tweak to your specific needs:

```
Charts.Add
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlPie
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A4"), PlotBy:= _
    xlColumns
ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="Sheet1"
ActiveChart.HasTitle = False
```

Comment: Hey mate.. Can i ask if you know how to put position in my chart?

Comment: What i found is to put .left ="something" and .top = "something" but i didn't manage to do it..

Comment: ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).Left = 100
ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).Top = 100